# Getting extra nulls when loading data into hive table while using regex delimiter

Tags: hive, null, hdfs, hive-serde

I have the following 5 lines of data in a file on hdfs. I want to load this to a table. I have regex that will do it, but it is loading an extra row of nulls for each line of data. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
19/Mar/2018 3:00:06 INFO activity Submitted to Splunk
19/Mar/2018 3:00:20 INFO activity response received statuscode=200 bytesreceived=11548264
19/Mar/2018 3:00:21 INFO activity done writing K:\Data\031818\activity_031818.csv lineswritten=296110
19/Mar/2018 3:00:21 INFO hardware Submitted to Splunk
```

I use this to create the table

```
create table Splunk_BCO_MSR 
(
ts string, 
status string, 
area string, 
text string
) 
partitioned by (partition_dt date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "([^ ]+[ ][^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (.*)?");
```

This almost works, however when I run a select * from the table, I get 8 rows instead of 4. It looks like there is an additional row of NULLS being added.

```
| 19/Mar/2018 3:00:06  | INFO              | activity  | Submitted to Splunk                                                                                                                                        | 2018-03-18                   |
| NULL                                     | NULL                   | NULL                       | NULL                                                                                                                                                                           | 2018-03-18                   |
| 19/Mar/2018 3:00:20  | INFO              | activity  | response received statuscode=200 bytesreceived=11548264                                                                | 2018-03-18                   |
| NULL                                     | NULL                   | NULL                       | NULL                                                                                                                                                                           | 2018-03-18                   |
| 19/Mar/2018 3:00:21  | INFO              | activity  | done writing K:\Data\031818\activity_031818.csv lineswritten=296110  | 2018-03-18                   |
| NULL                                     | NULL                   | NULL                       | NULL                                                                                                                                                                           | 2018-03-18                   |
| 19/Mar/2018 3:00:21  | INFO              | hardware  | Submitted to Splunk                                                                                                                                        | 2018-03-18                   |
| NULL                                     | NULL                   | NULL                       | NULL                                                                                                                                                                           | 2018-03-18
```

Comment: You might add delimiter to your query like: ` ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '`, which is space

Comment: I think that you should add delimiter to the row before add data to hive

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try tomorrow

Comment: So, row format delimited is replaced by row format serde in my script. That allows me to perform the right regex on the data... at least right until I get the duplicate line